# regex match last char in LF

Tags: regex, character, notepad++, line

I am trying to match last char in lines like :

```
11/30/2017 6:05:34 PM
11/16/2017 12:47:31 PM
11/28/2017 12:43:33 PM
11/21/2017 9:24:55 AM
```

as each line finishes with capital `M`, I thought it would be best to try to match `M`s. `[^M]\n` doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^M]` is a reverse character class. It matches anything *but* `M`.

An easy way to do this is to turn on the multiline option, so that `^` and `$` match the start and end of a line (as opposed to of the whole string), and use this regex

```
M$
```

If you don't have a multiline option, you can try

```
M(?=\n|$)
```

This uses a lookahead so the new line character won't be in the match.

Answer (score 0):

With `[^M]` you use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). This will match a character that is not `M`.

If you use [`M[\n]`](https://regex101.com/r/MhVaZM/1) you might not match the last one if it does not end with a newline.

You could use [`M$`](https://regex101.com/r/OMcnp3/1) to match `M` at the end of the string `$`.